# how datepicker without calendar for only month and year and change eventandler?

Tags: java, gwt, datepicker, calendar, widget

hi i need some help with my code

i need hide the calendar of the date picker but i dont know how

and change the handler selecting the month instead of the day

```
public void init(ParameterWidgetEventHandler eventHandler, final ParametroLite parameter, Document domParameters)
{
    dateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT)));

    super.init(eventHandler, parameter, domParameters);
```

Evento  Textbox for validate the information in the date

```
    dateBox.getTextBox().addKeyPressHandler(keyPressHandler);
```

Event of  dateBox selecting the date in the DatePicker

```
    dateBox.getDatePicker().addValueChangeHandler(valueChangeHandler);
    dateBox.getDatePicker().setYearArrowsVisible(true);
    dateBox.getDatePicker().setYearAndMonthDropdownVisible(true);
```

here load the restrictions

```
    listConstraint = domParameters.getElementsByTagName(AppConstants.WIDGET_CONSTRAIN);
    if(parameter.valor != null)
    {
        if(parameter.valor.equals(CURRENT_DATE))
        {
            dateBox.getTextBox().setValue(GWTUtil.simpleFormatDate(new Date()));
            checkConstraints();
        }
        else
        {
            if(parameter.widgetParameters.contains(AppConstants.WIDGET_FORMART_DATE))
                dateBox.getTextBox().setValue(GWTUtil.simpleFormatDate(parameter.valor, domParameters.getElementsByTagName(AppConstants.WIDGET_FORMART_DATE).item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()));
            else
                dateBox.getTextBox().setValue(parameter.valor);
            validateDate();
        }
    }

    setWidget(0, 0, dateBox);
}
//============================================================================================================  
private ValueChangeHandler<Date> valueChangeHandler = new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() 
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param event
     */
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) 
    {
        dateBox.setValue(event.getValue());
        checkConstraints();
    }
};
```